# CSS Pop up box that works in all browsers

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I want to display a pop up box when a visitor clicks on my google map marker. I already have the text I want to display when they click the marker.

Comment: All browsers? Even Lynx?

Comment: `...|/             ` (15 chars)

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a Google Maps instance, they already [have conventions for that](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html).

Comment: Also, this is covered in the very first tutorial: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/yourfirstmap.html

If you use v3 API, here's the demo: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/examples/infowindow-simple.html

Answer (score 0):

//assuming markers is an array of markers on your map

```
jQuery(markers).each(function(i,marker){

.click(function(){

    displayPoint(marker, i);

}
```